# This.setState causes the browser to hang + Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

```
var columns = []
    for (var key in this.props.col)
    {
        if (this.state.isEditing){
            columns.push(<td key = {key.id}><input ref = "txt" type = "text" value = { this.state.itemValue } onChange = { this.onTextChange.bind(this) } /></td>)
        }
        else
        {
            columns.push(<td key = {key.id}>{ this.props.col[key] }</td>)
            // this.setState({
            //  itemValue: key,
            //  isEditing: false
            // })
            console.log(key)
        }
        console.log(key);
    }
    return columns
```

Every time I uncomment this lines:

```
// this.setState({
            //  itemValue: key,
            //  isEditing: false
            // })
```

It causes the browser to hang. And a modal message shows up on the browser which says "a script on this page may be busy" and asking me whether to stop the script or continue. Thanks.

Comment: How are you calling this piece of code.

Comment: Where specifically are you setting the state? Remember, by default, when you setState, render() is called. So if you are setting state in render(), you're going to have this never ending loop.

Comment: Just some general feedback, you should avoid using String `ref` as they are considered legacy and most likely will be removed from React. Instead you should use `ref={(input) => { this.input = input }}`

Comment: @Dan Oh now I understand. Im calling the setState in a function which is then called inside render function. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you 'setState', your component will rerender, and I guess your function is called during the rendering phase (since it seems to build columns)